# How do I make my dropdown link stay blue when active

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am having trouble making the bootstrap accordion dropdown link stay blue when active. Tried varies things, and none of them worked. What am I doing wrong? Here's my code.

```
    <div class="visible-sm visible-xs" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                Advertise Jobs
              </h4>
         </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
           <h1>Reach the Right Candidates</h1>
           <p>Attract and recruit candidates by location, industry, specific skills and/or occupation</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                 Source Talent 
                </h4>
            </a>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
          <h1>Reach the Right Candidates</h1>
           <p>Attract and recruit candidates by location, industry, specific skills and/or occupation</p>


        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-2">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
              Recruit Socially
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

[JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p6f1jxgz/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to append a custom class to the toggled panel. You can do that with `jQuery`.

**Firstly,** add this to your JS:

```
jQuery('.panel-heading a').click(function() {
    $('.panel-heading').removeClass('open-panel');
    $(this).parents('.panel-heading').addClass('open-panel');
});
```

This will add the class `open-panel` to the active panel.

**Secondly,** add this to your css:

```
.open-panel h4 {
    background-color: #00aff0;
}
```

This will add the bg-color to the clicked panels.

**Thirdly,** change your html a bit so the blue bg will be there when the page loads. This can be done by manually adding the `open-panel` class to the default panel.

Change this:

```
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
```

To this:

```
<div class="panel-heading open-panel" role="tab">
```

Comment: Also, your fiddle was missing the `jQuery` file hence why the panels were not working.